# Standalone Arduino

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, atmega328, bootloader, icsp

I have an Arduino Uno and I am using arduino 1.0.5 IDE. I followed he procedures for bootloading an atmega328P-PU on a breadboard using an Arduino Uno from the link:

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoToBreadboard

I uploaded the ArduinoISP sketch first, made the connections(using the External Oscillator) and then wired it up. Then, I selected the programmer as Arduino as ISP, selected the board as Arduino duemilanove w/ Atmega328P . Then I selected the correct serial port and clicked Burn Bootloader. I got the following errors:

```
avrdude.exe: stk500_program_enable(): protocol error, expect=0x14,
resp=0x50avrdude.exe: initialization failed, rc=-1 Double check
connections and try again, or use -F to override this
check.avrdude.exe: stk500_disable(): protocol error, expect=0x14,
resp=0x51
```

How to solve this issue? Also, can I upload the bootloader directly by using it on the Uno in place of the original chip. If so, how?

Comment: `On the Arduino Uno, you'll need to connect a 10 uF capacitor between reset and ground (after uploading the ArduinoISP sketch)` [source](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/ArduinoISP ) (PS `<rant>`I'm getting very annoyed by the inaccuracies on the arduino website. New users continue to have to figure out why things don't work, while the problem has been known for years.`</rant>`)

Answer (score 1):

See [How to make an Arduino-compatible minimal board](http://www.gammon.com.au/breadboard).

> Also, can I upload the bootloader directly by using it on the Uno in place of the original chip.

No, a blank chip cannot install its own bootloader. You use a second chip. My page above describes how to do that. An alternative is a stand-alone ICSP programmer, which can be purchased for around $20. The tutorial page you linked uses your Uno as a stand-alone programmer.

I think my method of [using a Uno as a programmer](http://www.gammon.com.au/bootloader) is easier, frankly.

Comment: Hey, I followed your procedure for making Arduino Compatible minimal breadboard. I had to use an external oscillator. But when I run the code my output is not what it should be. I get the following output
"MD5 sum of bootloader = 0x6A 0xE5 0x9E 0x64 0x85 0x03 0x77 0xEE 0x54 0x70 0xC8 0x54 0x76 0x15 0x51 0xEA 
No bootloader (all 0xFF)"
What should i do now?

Comment: Please edit your question, and post the exact output (copy and paste) from the bootloader uploading program. Turn it into "code format" by selecting all of the output and hitting Ctrl+K.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; I never figured it out. I eventually threw down some cash for am ICSP (I got the FreeTronics USBASP), and have never looked back. In fact, with an ICSP, you don't even need a bootloader. It's also real easy to solder a 6-pin header onto your custom soldered board; then you will realize you don't need an Arduino at all, just an Atmel chip.